# pass ArrayList<Point> from one activity to another activity in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, point, points

how to pass the `ArrayList<Point>` from one activity to another activity ?

my arraylist is integer. I want to show the list of point on the next activity and do some calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Point already implements parcelable class, all you need to do is this in your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.add(new Point(3,5));
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("points", points);
startActivity(intent);
```

And this in your second

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Point> points = extras.getParcelableArrayList("points");
}
```